# how can i modify this query to get the count of a particular column?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables users, and products_users.

I want to get all users where their FBID as in a predetermined list...HOWEVER i also want to get the total count of how many times they appear in the products_users table... (this essentially shows how many different products a user "liked" on my site)

In the end I would want:

`user1, 4

user2, 7

user3, 28

etc.`

The issue is getting the count to work.

I have this currently:

```
select users.*
    , products_users.fbid
    , products_users.`graph_id` as objects_liked 
    from users 
        inner join products_users 
            on (products_users.`fbid` = users.fbid) 
            and products_users.`fbid` in ('0_fbid','1_fbid')
```

which results in the following:

[image]

However, instead I want each row to be a unique user and the objects_liked column to represent to TOTAL count.

Is there a way to do this? Please help!

FYI - I have already tried to change

```
products_users.`graph_id` as objects_liked
```

to

```
count(products_users.`graph_id`) as objects_liked
```

but that only results to:

[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it a bit confusing how you are expecting to get `user1, 4 user2, 7 user3, 28 etc.` as a result and you're selecting by `users.*, products_users.fbid, products_users.graph_id`. I assume the first result is the one you're expecting to get.

The following query will show you the users and the amount of times they appear in the products_users table (I understand that is what you're looking for). I'm guessing the `users` columns because you didn't provide them.

```
select users.name, count(*) as count_of_rows_in_products_users_table from users
inner join products_users on (products_users.fbid = users.fbid)
where products_users.fbid in ('0_fbid', '1_fbid')
group by users.name
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT Distinct UsersID, iResult.iCount
FROM Users LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT fbid, COUNT(*) as iCount 
     FROM products_users
     GROUP BY fbid) as iResult
```